# Error in library(leaflet) : there is no package called ‘leaflet’

Tags: r, docker, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I wrote the docker file like this to deploy the shiny r application

```
FROM rocker/r-base:latest\
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN install.r shiny
RUN install.r shinydashboard


RUN R -e "install.packages(c('ggmap','ggplot2','leaflet'),dependencies = TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"


RUN echo "local(options(shiny.port = 3838, shiny.host = '0.0.0.0'))" > /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site

RUN addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY app .

RUN chown app:app -R /home/app

USER app

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/app')"]
```

next, I build a docker file

```
docker build -t test-shiny .
```

after run the build docker image

```
docker run -p 3838:3838 test-shiny
```

this time I got an error like this

[image: error message]

my app Global.R file like this
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyMobile)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)

what I can do fix leaflet package issue,
someone can help me!

Comment: Check the `docker build` log for any errors about the `leaflet` install.

Comment: Looks like you tried to install shiny **before** you installed it’s dependencies.

Comment: hello, did you ever solve this? running into the same issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for that

```
RUN
sudo \
libgdal-dev \
libproj-dev \
libgeos-dev \
libudunits2-dev \
netcdf-bin \
```

Install these dependencies