# Docker can't find leaflet when deploying r shiny app

Tags: r, docker, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I've seen a few other posts about the same issue, but no clear solution from any of them.

When running `docker build -t test-shiny .`, I get the following error when running the docker image locally:

```
Error in library(leaflet) : there is no package called ‘leaflet’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
Execution halted
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/r-base:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    curl \
    wget \
    sudo \
    alien \
    redis-server \
    gnupg \
    unixodbc-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libpng-dev \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libhiredis-dev \
    libmagick++-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean \
    libgdal-dev \
    netcdf-bin 


# Athena ODBC Drivers
RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/ODBC/SimbaAthenaODBC_1.1.9.1001/Linux/simbaathena-1.1.9.1001-1.el7.x86_64.rpm && \
    sudo alien -i simbaathena-1.1.9.1001-1.el7.x86_64.rpm && \
    rm simbaathena-1.1.9.1001-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

# Dependencies
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("shiny",  "shinydashboard", "ggplot2", "patchwork","dbplyr", "dbplot", "scales", "shinycssloaders", "rJava", "RJDBC", "shinyjs", "shinyBS", "highcharter", "leaflet", "DT", "glue", "DBI", "odbc", "data.table"), dependencies = TRUE, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", Ncpus=5)' && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages

# Copy App
RUN mkdir shiny-app
COPY evaluation-app/ /shiny-app

# RShiny Port
EXPOSE 3838

# Run App
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/shiny-app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

I know I am installing a lot of r packages, but my app runs fine in RStudio. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819103/error-in-libraryleaflet-there-is-no-package-called-leaflet) post, I already tried adding the solution from the accepted answer, but unsuccessful. Any suggestions or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect leaflet is not being installed because of an error or missing dependency and the docker build is moving on to the next step without alerting you.

Comment: I think if you use install2.r to install packages, you can choose to stop the docker build on an error or even a warning. Maybe try that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, any idea on what that piece of code would look like?

Comment: https://www.rocker-project.org/use/extending/